# topmenu in magento 1.7 not working

Tags: xml, magento, navigation, menubar

I'm trying to create a fresh template in Magento, as opposed to using a cut and paste blank template and editing the css to suit my layout.  I want to add a topMenu of categories and pages as my main navigation.  I followed the instructions I've found all over the internet and the menu doesn't show in any situation.

The code I have in my page.xml is this for topMenu

```
        <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
            <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml" />
        </block>
```

and the code I have in my head file to call this is

```
<div id="utilities">  
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
</div>
```

The topmenu.phtml is in the /page/html/ folder of my theme, I've cleared out my cache and reindexed..nothing shows.

Strangely, the theme I copied the code from when I set it as the default, it actually shows the topMenu navigation with my categories and pages.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` in page/html/header.phtml
your header.phtml is rendered because of:

**App/Code/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php**

Line 38:

$this->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');

You are trying to get the topMenu block as child of this header block. This means that you must add that block in page.xml as child block of the header block.

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
            <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml" />
    </block>    
</block>
```

To make sure this will be called on all the pages (if not overridden) you have to put it in the default handle.

so that would look like this:

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml" />
        </block>    
    </block>
</default>
```

You can also change the template of the header file by changing it to:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header" template="page/html/custom_header.phtml">
</block>
```

Hope it helps !